# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Please!! Help me out why it is throwing "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access"

I have created a templates directory inside the project.

This is my project file structure:

```
> bin
>src
  >cli.js
  >main.js
> templates
  > javascript
    >src
    >package.json
>test-dir
>.gitignore
>LICENSE
>package.json
>readme.md
```

cli.js

```js
import arg from "arg";
import inquirer from "inquirer";
import { chakatiFire } from "./main.js";

function parseArgumnetsOptions(rawArguments) {
  let args = arg(
    {
      "--git": Boolean,
      "--help": Boolean,
      "--yes": Boolean,
      "--install": Boolean,
      "--g": "--git",
      "--h": "--help",
      "--y": "--yes",
      "--i": "--install",
    },
    {
      argv: rawArguments.slice(2),
    }
  );
  return {
    skipPrompts: args["--yes"] || false,
    git: args["--git"] || false,
    template: args._[0],
    runInstall: args["--install"] || false,
  };
}

async function promptErrorMissingOpts(opts) {
  const defaultTemplate = "JavaScript";
  if (opts.skipPrompts) {
    return {
      ...opts,
      template: opts.template || defaultTemplate,
    };
  }
  const displayOptions = [];
  if (!opts.template) {
    displayOptions.push({
      type: "list",
      name: "template",
      message: "What template would you like to use?",
      choices: ["JavaScript"],
      default: defaultTemplate,
    });
  }

  if (!opts.git) {
    displayOptions.push({
      type: "confirm",
      name: "git",
      message: "Would you like to use git?",
      default: false,
    });
  }

  const userInput = await inquirer.prompt(displayOptions);
  return {
    ...opts,
    template: opts.template || userInput.template,
    git: opts.git || userInput.git,
  };
}

export async function cli(args) {
  let opts = parseArgumnetsOptions(args);
  opts = await promptErrorMissingOpts(opts);
  // console.log(opts);
  await chakatiFire(opts);
}
```

main.js

```js
import chalk from "chalk";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import ncp from "ncp";
import { promisify } from "util";

// access
const access = promisify(fs.access);

// reccusive copy
const copy = promisify(ncp);

// async function to copy template files
async function copyTemplateFiles(opts) {
  return copy(opts.templateDirectory, opts.targetDirectory, {
    clobber: false,
  });
}

export async function chakatiFire(opts) {
  opts = {
    ...opts,
    targetDirectory: opts.targetDirectory || process.cwd(),
  };

  const fullPathName = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
  const templateDir = path.resolve(
    fullPathName.substr(fullPathName.indexOf("/")),
    "../../templates",
    opts.template.toLowerCase()
  );
  opts.templateDirectory = templateDir;

  try {
    await access(templateDir, fs.constants.R_OK);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(chalk.red(`Template directory ${templateDir} does not exist`));
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("Copy project files");
  await copyTemplateFiles(opts);
  console.log(chalk.green(`Creating project from template ${opts.template}`));
  return true;
}
```

when i run the command(chakati-fire javascript --git) inside test-dir it throws ERROR like this =>

PS D:\JavaScript_Projects\chakati\chakati-fire\test-dir> chakati-fire javascript --git
Template directory D:\D:\JavaScript_Projects\chakati\chakati-fire\templates\javascript does not exist
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'D:\D:\JavaScript_Projects\chakati\chakati-fire\templates\javascript'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'access',
path: 'D:\D:\JavaScript_Projects\chakati\chakati-fire\templates\javascript'
}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is causing for extra `D:\` at the beginning. So, we have to remove the first 3 characters from the `templateDir` variable using `templateDir.substring(3)`.

### Here is the solution

Updated `main.js`

```
import chalk from "chalk";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import ncp from "ncp";
import { promisify } from "util";

// access
const access = promisify(fs.access);

// reccusive copy
const copy = promisify(ncp);

// async function to copy template files
async function copyTemplateFiles(opts) {
  return copy(opts.templateDirectory, opts.targetDirectory, {
    clobber: false,
  });
}

export async function chakatiFire(opts) {
  opts = {
    ...opts,
    targetDirectory: opts.targetDirectory || process.cwd(),
  };

  const fullPathName = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
  let templateDir = path.resolve(
    fullPathName.substr(fullPathName.indexOf("/")),
    "../../templates",
    opts.template.toLowerCase()
  );
  templateDir = templateDir.substring(3);  // <-- This is the fix.
  opts.templateDirectory = templateDir;

  try {
    await access(templateDir, fs.constants.R_OK);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(chalk.red(`Template directory ${templateDir} does not exist`));
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("Copy project files");
  await copyTemplateFiles(opts);
  console.log(chalk.green(`Creating project from template ${opts.template}`));
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The path you get from your code is `D:\D:\JavaScript_Projects\chakati\chakati-fire\templates\javascript` (double `D:\`), which doesn't exist.